# Python Reference requirements in other requirements file

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I have a file with pip install requirements for a repo (requirements.txt). For testing I have another file (requirements_tests.txt) that should contain same requirements and more. Can I reference requirements.txt from inside requirements_tests.txt?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brequirements.txt%5D+include+another

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution

Add `-r requirements.txt` at first line i.e. `-r path/to/file` in your `requirements_test.txt`.
Which means when you do `pip install -r requirements_test.txt` it will come at line `-r requirements.txt` and will install all it's requirement and will again continue in `requirements_test.txt`

### E.g.

requirements.txt

```
pandas
numpy
matplotlib
```

requirements_test.txt

```
-r requirements.txt
tox
pytest
black
flake
```

PS: There are some other options also depending on what you are using for managing the environment or any other packages for managing different environments from a single file.

**[Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/)** manages Python virtual environment, environment-based dependency management, build, and publish.
There's also **[Hatch](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/)** which is adopted by PyPa. Seems hacky to use at the moment but follows PEP guidelines and adopts new guidelines.